# Julia: how I "fix" a package at a particular version?

Tags: package, julia

How do I "fix" a package at particular version? in Julia?

So that we don't have to update a package if it breaks existing code.

Comment: Type `?Pkg.pin` at the REPL

Comment: Actually, I decided to give a more formal answer since I suspect this question will be searched fairly frequently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**After v1.0**

My original answer to this question is now syntactically outdated. @RikH has provided an answer with the latest syntax. For additional info beyond that answer regarding the syntactical differences between working in the REPL package mode or the regular REPL, type `using Pkg`, and then `?Pkg.PackageSpec` at the REPL to see examples of the ways in which package versions/commits etc can be referenced

**Before v1.0**

The process for doing this is described pretty clearly in the [official docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/packages/). However, I suspect this question will be searched for frequently, so perhaps it doesn't hurt to double up.

Packages can be pinned to a specific version using `Pkg.pin`. The single input method will pin the package to the current version:

```
julia> Pkg.pin("DependentBootstrap")
INFO: Creating DependentBootstrap branch pinned.b32df31a.tmp

julia> Pkg.status()
13 required packages:
...
 - DependentBootstrap            0.1.0              pinned.b32df31a.tmp
 - ForecastEval                  0.1.0
```

where you'll note the package has been pinned to a specific git commit.

You can pin to a specific tagged version of a particular package using a second argument:

```
julia> Pkg.pin("DependentBootstrap", v"0.0.1")
INFO: Creating DependentBootstrap branch pinned.996d3c22.tmp
INFO: Downgrading ForecastEval: v0.1.0 => v0.0.1
INFO: Building SpecialFunctions
INFO: Building Rmath

julia> Pkg.status()
13 required packages:
...
 - DependentBootstrap            0.0.1              pinned.996d3c22.tmp
 - ForecastEval                  0.0.1
```

Notice that the pinning operation automatically downgraded `ForecastEval` in order to satisfy version requirements.

You can get the package back to the latest stable version using `Pkg.free`:

```
julia> Pkg.free("DependentBootstrap")
INFO: Freeing DependentBootstrap
INFO: Upgrading ForecastEval: v0.0.1 => v0.1.0
INFO: Building SpecialFunctions
INFO: Building Rmath

julia> Pkg.status()
13 required packages:
...
 - DependentBootstrap            0.1.0
 - ForecastEval                  0.1.0
```

Notice that `ForecastEval` has also automatically returned to the latest version.

Comment: `Pkg.pin("DependentBootstrap", v"0.0.1")` returns "no method matching pin(::String, ::VersionNumber)" in Julia 1.0.5

Answer (score 3):

This question has been answered in [How to pin a package to a certain version using Julia 0.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215654) for Julia 0.7. The following can be used in Julia 1.0 (and 0.7 it seems).

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add(PackageSpec(name = "GDAL", version = "0.1.2"))
Pkg.pin(PackageSpec(name = "GDAL", version = "0.1.2"))
```

or in the REPL package mode

```
julia> ]
pkg> add GDAL@0.1.2
pkg> pin GDAL@0.1.2
```

Note that if you use `PackageSpec`, then only using `Pkg.add` will install the correct version (tested with Docker Image "julia:1.0.5-buster").

Comment: That gave me `Pkg.pin(PackageSpec(name = "JuMP", version ="0.18"))
ERROR: UndefVarError: PackageSpec not defined` but `(@v1.5) pkg> pin JuMP@0.18` worked well so I guess it's ok

Comment: That's odd, for me that exact code just worked. I used Julia 1.5, just like you. It might be that `using Pkg` was necessary before `Pkg.add`, so I have updated the answer.

Answer (score -2):

For the last update of pkg package, the accepted answer no longer works.
You must specify the version after the @ symbol. `pin Example@0.1.0`

```
(v1.1) pkg> pin CSV@0.4.2
 Resolving package versions...
 Installed CSV ─ v0.4.2
  Updating `C:\Users\S\.julia\environments\v1.1\Project.toml`
  [336ed68f] ↓ CSV v0.4.3 ⇒ v0.4.2 ⚲
  Updating `C:\Users\S\.julia\environments\v1.1\Manifest.toml`
  [336ed68f] ↓ CSV v0.4.3 ⇒ v0.4.2 ⚲
```

⚲ means that the version is sucsesfully pinned.

Updated link to the [official manual](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/managing-packages/)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your solution to explain exactly how it aligns with / updates the existing accepted answer. Thanks.