# How to pin a package to a certain version using Julia 0.7?

Tags: julia

I'm using Atom Julia 0.7 on Ubuntu. I'd like to pin the package GDAL to version 0.1.2.

I found this link, [Julia: how I "fix" a package at a particular version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087509/julia-how-i-fix-a-package-at-a-particular-version) but need more detailed information.

```
Julia> Pkg.pin(PackageSpec(name = “GDAL”, version = “0.1.2”))

Error: the following package names could not be resolved: * GDAL(add… in manifest but not in project) Please specify by known ‘name=uuid’.
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can pin a package to a specific version, it needs to be added.

As [docstring documented](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/blob/853b3f1fd9895db32b402d89e9dee153b66b2316/src/Pkg.jl#L329), this should work:

```
Pkg.add(PackageSpec(name = "GDAL", version = "0.1.2"))
Pkg.pin(PackageSpec(name = "GDAL", version = "0.1.2"))
```

Or in the REPL Pkg mode (`]`)

```
pkg> add GDAL@0.1.2
pkg> pin GDAL@0.1.2
```

Note that pin by default pins the currently used version, so if you already specify the version on `add`, you can leave it out for `pin`. The reverse also works, i.e. add the latest version, then `pin` an older one.

As an aside, the latest GDAL.jl release, v0.2.0, should work fine on julia 0.7. If it doesn't, please submit an issue :)